# How to use JPA generated values before persist

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a unique tracking number for all my DB entries by concatenating the current year with the generated id (also my PK) value. e.g. 2020-1, but I’m getting a null pointer exception since the id is generated for each record on persist.

Here’s my code.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@PrePersist
public void onCreate() {
    this.tracking_number = new SimpleDateFormat(“yyyy”).format(new Date())+”-“+getId().toString();
}
```

Comment: Well you cannot, as it is the db that is assigning the value and that simply isn't availabe before persisting it.